# How do whitening toothbrushes work?

Tags: everyday-life, friction

Certain "whitening" toothbrushes are sold and I was wondering about the mechanisms behind the tooth whitening process. I suspect this is related to the shape and arrangement of the  fibres, probably somewhat similar to how a microfiber cleaning cloth works, but couldn't find any authoritative confirmation.

So how does a whitening toothbrush work? I'm only interested in the physical effects - whitening toothpastes rely on their chemical properties so they're a completely different story.

Comment: I've found loads of toothbrushes out there that advertise themselves as whitening. They claim to work different ways. Did you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: There are many ways these things could work. I have seen some in the past that simply had some sort of dye based on titanium oxyde (same thing that makes Mentos white), so you'd be basically "painting" your teeth with it.

Comment: @Renan: I think that you refer to the toothpaste, while the OP refers to the toothbrush.

Comment: @rodrigo No, I really have seen tooth **brushes** with embedded dye. I know that many pastes have it in their formula so as to be white, but in this case I do mean the little hairs in the brush.

Comment: If you accept that whitening pastes (the ones that don't use paint) work by [just being more abrasive](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19177/does-baking-soda-remove-stains-from-your-teeth), then sure a more abrasive brush would have the same effect. Then again, one should be [skeptical of claims that some toothbrushes are magically better than others](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/do-modern-toothbrush-features-remove-more-plaque-than-regular-toothbrushes).

Comment: You should post a preliminary question on [Skeptics.SX](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com): *Do whitening toothbrushes actually work?*

Comment: at least some of them (and some older) used soda

Comment: @HDE226868 If there are many different mechanisms, I'm interested in all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitening toothbrushes remove surface stains or to put it another way literally remove deposits that are darker than your teeth were before they were stained.

Comment: So how does the action which you describe differ from what a standard toothbrush does?

Comment: How does this picture help here? The No.3 tooth even repositioned itself.

Comment: Wow!  A toothbrush that straightens teeth!  That one will have blockbuster sales!